# InDesign: how to import a Photoshop file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, file-placing

How to import a photoshop graphic into InDesign? Can I then edit the file in InDesign or do I have to edit first in Photoshop (crop and write text)?

Answer (score 2):

When working with InDesign, you can import a PSD file saved in Photoshop by using the Place command, found via "Main menu > File > Place" or via the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.

You generally cannot edit a PSD file in InDesign, most edits will need to be done in Photoshop, however cropping is possible in InDesign after importing. You can easily re-crop a placed file.

- Read more here: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/placing-graphics.html

Note that every time you edit an imported (placed) file, you will have to update the link so InDesign renders your latest revision. With your InDesign document open, go to "Window > Links" to see a list of all placed (linked) files.

- Read more here: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/graphics-links.html

Answer (score 2):

Use File > Place to import your photo. InD lets you to position, resize, crop, rotate, make transparent, fade gradually, shear, add edge shadow or glow, but not to edit the content.

From links panel you can launch Photoshop for editing. Beware: It takes the original under the work.

Texts can be constructed in InD over the photos, too.